# grant user privileges identical to another user

Tags: mysql, database, privileges, sql-grant

How can I give one user the identical set of privileges as another (pre-existing) user?

I can do:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user1'
```

But not:

```
GRANT (SHOW GRANTS for 'user1') to 'user2';
```

or

```
CREATE USER 'user1' LIKE 'user2'
```

So I can't see a way programmatically add all these grants a different `user2` in an SQL way (other than writing a script in an app language to iterate thru that SHOW GRANTS)

Maybe there is a way going to the `mysql.user` table? Or is that a bad idea in general? I am not particularly knowledgeable about, or comfortable messing around with, that table.

Comment: [MySQL Utilities](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities/) provide a tool, [mysqluserclone](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/en/mysqluserclone.html), that does exactly what you want.  Otherwise, you can indeed effect such a change by operating on the [Privilege System Grant Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/grant-table-structure.html) directly (provided that you `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` when you're done).